# Get color name from RGB code?

Tags: android, image-processing, rgb, color-picker

I have this piece of code that gets the RGB color when an image is clicked:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable())
                        .getBitmap();
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                greenValue = Color.green(pixel); 


                tv_selected_colour.setText(""+redValue+""+blueValue+""+greenValue);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

I need to sort out the **color name** (red, green, etc) from the RGB value. Is that possible?

Comment: Color name? That is a bit absurd in modern times, who has time to lookup 16.7 million different names?

Comment: yeah but this is my project requirements

Comment: sth like: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fmodel%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fmodel%2Fapi%2Futil%2FColorUtil.html ??

Comment: Make a table in SQLite with the color names and their definitions in hex? Pass the color and get the name. But, since I'm not prone to believe that you'll insert over 16 millions color names, mostly you'll get "Undefined" (or NULL)

Comment: Maybe he just wants 'approximate' color names, so very, very dark gray will give 'Black'

Comment: Or even "Something in between Purple and Violet".

Comment: static final String colordesc[][] =
  {
          { "white","255255255" },
          { "balck","#000" }       
        
} ; i am going to save colors in arry like this .. then now compare array value with the RGB value ?? is it works ??

Answer (score 3):

A few years ago, Randall Monroe (of XKCD) did a [large online survey of English-speakers](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) that resulted in a [list of over 900 colour names](http://xkcd.com/color/rgb.txt). You could easily use this data as the basis of a colour naming function that converts an RGB triplet into the name of the closest colour. This is what a simple implementation would look like in C, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define squared(X) ((X) * (X))

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  unsigned char r, g, b;
} color_name;

/* Source: http://xkcd.com/color/rgb.txt */
/* License: http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/ */
static const color_name xkcd_colors[] = {
  {"cloudy blue",0xac,0xc2,0xd9}, {"dark pastel green",0x56,0xae,0x57},
  {"dust",0xb2,0x99,0x6e}, {"electric lime",0xa8,0xff,0x04},
           :
      (et cetera)
           :
  {"blue",0x03,0x43,0xdf}, {"green",0x15,0xb0,0x1a},
  {"purple",0x7e,0x1e,0x9c}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int red, green, blue, d2, mind2, i, result;
  if (argc != 2 ||sscanf(argv[1],"%02x%02x%02x",&red,&green,&blue) != 3)
    return !puts("Provide 6 hex chars as command line argument.");

  mind2 = 256 * 256 * 3;
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(xkcd_colors)/sizeof(color_name); i++) {
    d2 = squared(red - xkcd_colors[i].r) +    /* Calculate squared  */
         squared(green - xkcd_colors[i].g) +  /* distance from each */
         squared(blue - xkcd_colors[i].b);    /* color in list.     */
    if (d2 < mind2) {
      mind2 = d2;   /* Find the minimum distance and */
      result = i;   /* store the index of this color */
    }
  }
  printf("That color is called \"%s\"\n",xkcd_colors[result].name);
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** You might want to base your function on a different data set if you don't want it to return results like "baby shit brown" (#ad900d) or "puke" (#a5a502), but the principle is the same.